# Problems with R.layout.main

Tags: android

I am having a hard time trying to get my way around this. I just started a new project, and without doing anything the project shows this error at the `mainactivity.java` src, right at this line...

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

gives me "R cannot be resolve to a variable", ok, "quick fixes" gives me among others the option to import R, I go ahead and do it, then I got a new error " activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field" and then quick fixes gives me just one option, "change to activity_list_item", so my question is: why all this is happening?

and then on this method

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
```

I get same error at `R.menu.main`, but now I do not get any options???

I am having a hard time with this `R.java`. I tried all possible fixes I found at this forum but none of them work.
help please. thanks

Comment: Using Eclipse and the ADT?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, Eclipse will default to using android.R instead of com.your.package.R. Go to your imports section and check that you are importing your package's R file.

Then perform a directory refresh and a clean. This should fix your problem or expose another problem.

It could also be that you have cleaned your project and you have an error in some xml file, which will prevent R.java from being generated.

Comment: This may or may not be @user1540556 's current problem but it's almost certain that this problem will happen sooner or later.  It's very common in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

are you importing com.your.project.package.name and not com.actionbarsherlock for example ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `import android.R;` in your activity java file